# Docker, cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have created Dockerfile, when i'm try to run a problem inside my container i'm getting error:

> bash: xxx: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

Dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:buster-slim

# Set the working directory to /usr/local/bin
WORKDIR /usr/local/bin

# Build container and setup wallet
RUN apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get autoremove -y && \
    apt-get install wget -y && \
    wget https://euno.co/wallet/euno-2.0.2.tar.gz && \
    tar zxvf euno-2.0.2.tar.gz && \
    rm -rf euno-2.0.2.tar.gz && \
    mkdir /root/.eunopay && \
    chmod 755 euno*

# change working dir to eunopay folder
WORKDIR /root/.eunopay

# Download bootstrap
RUN wget https://euno.co/bootstrap/euno-bootstrap.tar.gz && \
    tar zxvf euno-bootstrap.tar.gz && \
    rm -rf euno-bootstrap.tar.gz && \
    echo "server=1" >> euno.conf && \
    echo "deamon=1" >> euno.conf && \
    echo "debug=0" >> euno.conf

WORKDIR /root
ENTRYPOINT [ "/bin/bash", "-l", "-c" ]
```

Can anyone help me out what's going wrong?

Comment: not sure why you have used bash -l -c without any string parameter after it. The entrypoint here does not seem to run any command in the container in the foreground. Can you also share your full docker logs? Also is the error during docker build or you're getting the error while running your application.

Comment: you are using the slim image `debian:buster-slim` which probably doesn't have the `bin/bash` and hence the error, try a different image which has `bash` installed.

Comment: I tried running your `Dockerfile` but when trying to download `https://euno.co/wallet/euno-2.0.2.tar.gz` I get error 404. Also share your output so that we can help you more. What command do you run?

Comment: What is the output of `uname -a`?